# Make a Call in on number followed by # key

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am working on the calling app where I make call on button click but if the number just followed by # then it does not take the # key at the last of phone number.

For Example if I want to make a call on *123# from app then it only shows *123 in the calling screen in phone.  Please suggest me where I am going wrong.

Here is my code for call on *123# on button click.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "*123#"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 3):

try this...

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+ Uri.encode("*123#")));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the # as a URI entity: %23

Comment: callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "*123%23"));