# # not appearing when dialing from android

Tags: android

I have an android app which shows USSD codes of telecom companies, codes come from .sql database but the '#' sigh does not appear when dialing though it is there in the database

```
@Override
public void onPhoneClicked(Entry entry) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("tel:%s", entry.getPhoneNumber())));
    mcontext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143747/make-a-call-in-on-number-followed-by-key/20144055#20144055

Comment: Can you please show me on my code ?

Comment: what is the sample value returned by `entry.getPhoneNumber()`?

Comment: Sorr,y but how exactly do I get it?

Comment: replace `intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("tel:%s", entry.getPhoneNumber())));` with `intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+Uri.encode(entry.getPhoneNumber())));`...